# PHP header 200 OK doesn't get sent

Tags: php, cakephp, http-headers

I am trying to send HTTP/1.0 200 OK from within a controller inside CakePHP

but everytime I do that, the browser received HTTP 404 Not Found instead.

Following https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27026, I have to send

```
HTTP/1.0 299 OK
```

Any idea what am I missing ?

Apache version  2.2.21

PHP version     5.3.8

CakePHP 2.0

-- EDIT --

I am using the code from http://rakaz.nl/projects/combine/combine.phps to combine my javascript and css

i.e.
http://www.creatype.nl/javascript/prototype.js,builder.js,effects.js,dragdrop.js,slider.js

```
        public function combineJs($filenames) {
        $this->combine($filenames, 'javascript');
    }

    public function combineCss($filenames) {
        $this->combine($filenames, 'css');
    }

    private function combine($filenames = null, $type = null) {
        $cache    = true;
        $cachedir = ROOT.'/app/tmp/cache/combine';
        $cssdir   = ROOT.'/app/webroot/css';
        $jsdir    = ROOT.'/app/webroot/js';


        // Determine the directory and type we should use
        switch ($type) {
            case 'css':
                $base = $cssdir;
                break;
            case 'javascript':
                $base = $jsdir;
                break;
            default:
                header ("HTTP/1.0 503 Not Implemented");
                exit;
        };

        $elements = explode(',', $filenames);
        $elements = str_replace('%2F', '/', $elements);
        // Determine last modification date of the files
        $lastmodified = 0;
        while (list(,$element) = each($elements)) {

            $path = $base . '/' . $element;

            if (($type == 'javascript' && substr($path, -3) != '.js') || 
                ($type == 'css' && substr($path, -4) != '.css')) {
                header ("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
                exit;   
            }

            if (substr($path, 0, strlen($base)) != $base || !file_exists($path)) {

                header ("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
                exit;
            }

            $lastmodified = max($lastmodified, filemtime($path));
        }

        // Send Etag hash
        $hash = $lastmodified . '-' . md5( $filenames );
        header ("ETag: \"" . $hash . "\"");


        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) && 
            stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) == '"' . $hash . '"') 
        {

            // Return visit and no modifications, so do not send anything
            header ("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
            header ('Content-Length: 0');
        } 
        else 
        {
            // First time visit or files were modified
            if ($cache) 
            {
                // Determine supported compression method
                $gzip = strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip');
                $deflate = strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'deflate');

                // Determine used compression method
                $encoding = $gzip ? 'gzip' : ($deflate ? 'deflate' : 'none');

                // Check for buggy versions of Internet Explorer
                if (!strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera') && 
                    preg_match('/^Mozilla\/4\.0 \(compatible; MSIE ([0-9]\.[0-9])/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches)) {
                    $version = floatval($matches[1]);

                    if ($version < 6)
                        $encoding = 'none';

                    if ($version == 6 && !strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'EV1')) 
                        $encoding = 'none';
                }

                // Try the cache first to see if the combined files were already generated
                $cachefile = 'cache-' . $hash . '.' . $type . ($encoding != 'none' ? '.' . $encoding : '');

                if (file_exists($cachedir . '/' . $cachefile)) {

                    if ($fp = fopen($cachedir . '/' . $cachefile, 'rb')) {

                        if ($encoding != 'none') {
                            header ("Content-Encoding: " . $encoding);
                        }

                        header ("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
                        header ("Content-Type: text/" . $type);
                        header ("Content-Length: " . filesize($cachedir . '/' . $cachefile));

                        fpassthru($fp);
                        fclose($fp);

                        exit;
                    }
                } 
            }

            // Get contents of the files
            $contents = '';
            reset($elements);
            while (list(,$element) = each($elements)) {
                $path = $base . '/' . $element;
                $contents .= "\n\n" . file_get_contents($path);
            }

            // Send Content-Type
            // header ("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");

            // for some reason, header 200 OK doesn't get sent, so send 299 instead
            header ("HTTP/1.0 299 OK");
            header ("Content-Type: text/" . $type);

            if (isset($encoding) && $encoding != 'none') 
            {
                // Send compressed contents
                $contents = gzencode($contents, 9, $gzip ? FORCE_GZIP : FORCE_DEFLATE);
                header ("Content-Encoding: " . $encoding);
                header ('Content-Length: ' . strlen($contents));

                echo $contents;
            } 
            else 
            {
                // Send regular contents
                header ('Content-Length: ' . strlen($contents));
                header ("Content-Type: text/" . $type);
                echo $contents;
            }

            // Store cache
            if ($cache) {

                $filepath = $cachedir . '/' . $cachefile;
                $file = new File( $filepath );
                $file->write($contents);
                $file->close();
            }

            exit;
        }
```

Comment: Except that bug was marked fixed back in 2004.  If you're getting a 404 error, check your logs and make sure that you're actually hitting the script you're trying to hit.

Comment: You don't have to send 200 manually. CakePHP does that automatically in normal actions. Some details would help, otherwise this question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and almost threw a cup through my monitor. You may need to use the alternate syntax for your header call:

```
header('Status: 200');
```

It appears to be an issue with the way PHP interacts with the server.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this for creating health status reports for AWS load balancing.

Directing the incoming check to a webpage that loads properly was what did the trick for me.

I directed the status checker to www.yourdomain.com and the correct signal was returned.

Try loading the page in your browser with debug set to 2.  If cake returns errors, than you won't be sending the right signal.  Create a view file for your controller such that no errors are retured and you will likely start generating the correct signal.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with CakePHP router and the way I expected it to work. It doesn't like % char in the url and it throws 404 if it sees % in the URL